# Big Green Button

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to make a large button with 2 lines of text that looks something like:

[What I want](http://i1346.photobucket.com/albums/p697/Dunnskin/whatIwant_zpscfca58a1.png)

This is my current [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPh53/) showing what I've "accomplished"

I am fairly new to asp.net and programming in general so excuse my poor CSS.

Thanks for any help that anyone can offer.

The HTML:

```
<div class="bigGreenButton"> <a href="/Liquor/specialorder/supplier-info">Submit a special order request <br />
for information ➧
</a> </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.bigGreenButton a{
font-family:'TradeGothic LT CondEighteen';
font-size:18px;
background-color:#60a74a;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:25px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-decoration:none;
height:auto;
width:auto;
text-align:center;
}

.bigGreenButton a:hover {
 background-color:#cccccc;
}

button {
text-align: center;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border: none;
}
```

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/XPh53/3/

Comment: I feel like an idiot as for how easy this was.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It was not easy for a beginner. So don't feel bad at all, you will get there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.bigGreenButton a{
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
```

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmdv9/).

Answer (score 0):

Change display since there's not a block inside your link and set the width how you want it.

```
.bigGreenButton a{
    ...
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wsxpH/)